# How to have a specific node survive when a required node dies from a roslaunch?

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let's say I have nodes A, B, C ... Z. I want for nodes C to Z to die when A dies, but for B to continue executing and ignore that A died. I know I can use the required="true" argument on A in the roslaunch file to kill other nodes when it dies, but is there a way to tell roslaunch to not kill B?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271193/how-to-have-a-specific-node-survive-when-a-required-node-dies-from-a-roslaunch?/) by [Wesley](https://answers.ros.org/users/23234/wesley/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, roslaunch cannot do this.

If your launch process is this complex, you may want to rethink your launch process, use separate launch files or write your own process management. Roslaunch has an API that may be useful.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1